# Merge two json arrays into one array in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have multiple json files containing a json array object in the following format.

```json
[
    {
        "appId": "1",
        "userName": "zrqxnav2ktobg5ph4y6inxm4t22oqxnj",
        "appManagerError": {
            "errorCode": "",
            "errorMsg": ""
        },
        "endpoints": [
            {
                "path": "unknown"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I would like to merge all the json files [in the same format] in a single file.
something like this.

```json
[
    {
        "appId": "1",
        "userName": "zrqxnav2ktobg5ph4y6inxm4t22oqxnj",
        "appManagerError": {
            "errorCode": "",
            "errorMsg": ""
        },
        "endpoints": [
            {
                "path": "unknown"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "appId": "2",
        "userName": "zrjsjdsj34sdkjskt22oqxnj",
        "appManagerError": {
            "errorCode": "",
            "errorMsg": ""
        },
        "endpoints": [
            {
                "path": "known"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Fortunately, I was able to get this done in the shell using jq.

```
 cat temp1.json temp2.json | jq -s add > temp.json || exit $?
```

But I can't find anything similar in python.

Comment: Examples to help you get started: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/json

Answer (score 0):

```py
import json

content = []
filenames = ['temp1.json', 'temp2.json']
for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        content += json.load(f)
with open('temp.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(content, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: It actually merges arrays as it is just like a concatenation of two. However I want these two to be clubbed in a single array, please look at my expected output. It actually trims [] in between

Comment: @RajivRai Your JSON had missing closing curly brackets (`}`), had trailing commas where it shoulnd't and was poorly indented, but aside from that this answer is providing the output you requested. It was doing so in a single line so I added the `indent=4` keyword argument to have it pretty-printed now. I don't understand what you are saying in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that following code assuming that `json_list` is a list containing all yours stringified json files

```
from itertools import chain
import json

dictios = list()
for e in json_list:
    dictios.append(json.loads(e))

merged =  json.dumps(dict(chain.from_iterable(d.items() for d in dictios)))
```

`merged` will contain a stringified json which is the fusion of all your previous json files